# string operations - weird characters

Tags: c, unix

Description:

I read userinput (e.g "ls -l /") with fgets() and invoke Parse() where it gets seperated ("ls" "-l" "\") for later usage.

The Problem is: the tokens from the the first cycle have weird characters(screenshot below) in it, but from thereon the output is fine.
I tried to initialize both Buffers with zeroes with no change in behaviour. Please explain what is happening in my first output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/times.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <errno.h>

typedef char* string;
char inputBuffer[512];
string parse[256];
int j,parseCount;
void Parse(void);


void Parse(void)
{
    char buffer[512];
    string token;
    token = " ";
    strcpy(buffer, inputBuffer);
    j=0;
    parse[j] = strtok (buffer, token); 
    while (parse[j] != NULL)
    {
        j++;
        parse[j] = strtok (NULL, token); 
    }
    parseCount =j;  
}

int main (void)
{
    printf(">> ");
    fgets(inputBuffer, 512, stdin);   /* input buffer, max.Input(char), whereFrom?*/
    Parse();
    for (j=0;j<parseCount;j++){
         printf("[%d] %s\n",j, parse[j]);
    }
    return main(); 
}
```

[image: output]

Comment: What is `inputBuffer`?

Comment: Is the `string` type "`std::string`"?  If so, please change the C tag to C++.  If not, please include the type's definition here.

Comment: its C from <string.h> and inputBuffer was a typo. meant was iBuffer

Comment: I'm not a C++ expert by any means, but in the world of microsoft's C# in the .NET framework, typically seeing characters like that means you got the unicode encoding wrong.  This could be mean your input was UTF-16 and your output is UTF-7, or your parser is expecting UTF-16 and is reading 2 character codes per read (since the input could be UTF8), thereby combining character codes that don't belong together.

Comment: dare i ask ? `return main();` ???

Comment: There is still both "ibuffer" and "iBuffer" there as well as no definition of parseCount, which makes it look like the whole question was written in a hurry. Why not minimize the work of people trying to assist by giving something that readily compiles.

Comment: There's no `string` type in C, ryt?

Comment: @ al-Kwharizi my mistake. string isnt part of string.h, I made a "typdef char* string"

Comment: @ Whoz I dont want to end the main() except for user input (or seg faults :D ), would a while(true) behave differently ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line

```
parse[j] = strtok (buffer, token);
```

stores memory addresses in `buffer`, which is local to `Parse()`. The memory representing `buffer` is invalidated upon the return of `Parse()`, so also the addresses stored in `parse` aren't valid anymore when trying to be dereferenced to print what they refer to.

To fix this have the calling function create a temporary working buffer and pass down to `Parse() a reference to it:

```
char * parse[256] = 0;
char buffer[512] = "";
size_t parseCount = 0;

void Parse(char * buffer)
{
  const char * token = " ";
  size_t j = 0;
  parse[j] = strtok(buffer, token);
  while (parse[j] != NULL)
  {
    j++;
    parse[j] = strtok(NULL, token);
  }
  parseCount = j;
}

int main(void)
{
  fgets(buffer, 512, stdin);
  {
    char buffer_tmp[512];
    strcpy(buffer_tmp, buffer);
    Parse(buffer_tmp);

    for (size_t j = 0; j < parseCount; j++)
    {
      printf("[%zu] %s\n", j, parse[j]);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

As I don't like the globals, I'd prefer the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

size_t parse(char * buffer, char ** parse)
{
  const char * token = " ";
  size_t j = 0;
  parse[j] = strtok(buffer, token);
  while (parse[j] != NULL)
  {
    j++;
    parse[j] = strtok(NULL, token);
  }
  return j;
}

#define IN_MAX (512 + 1 + 1)

int main(void)
{
  char buffer[IN_MAX] = "";

  if (NULL != fgets(buffer, IN_MAX, stdin))
  {
    char buffer_tmp[IN_MAX];
    strcpy(buffer_tmp, buffer);

    {
      size_t parse_count = 0;
      char * parse[IN_MAX/2 + 1] = 0; 
      size_t parse_count = parse(buffer_tmp, parse);

      for (size_t j = 0; j < parse_count; j++)
      {
        printf("[%zu] %s\n", j, parse[j]);
      }
    }
  }
  else if (ferror())
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error reading from inout stream.\n");
  }

  return 0;
}
```